# Change fontawesome icon on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of songs that all have a play button (fontawesome).  I want to click one of them and change the icon from a play button to a pause button.  If I click another song's play button, the other icons need to change back to play buttons.  The icon does not change when I click it, although it does play my song.  Thanks

Here is my view and foreach loop.  Th eplay button is the one starting with `<td><a href=`

```
@foreach (var song in popularsongs.OrderByDescending(song => song.Fightsong.PlayCount).Take(5))
{
    <tr>
        <td onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Details", "Team", new {id = song.Teams.TeamId})'">
            <img src="@Url.Content(@song.Teams.LogoUrl)" height="35" width="35"/>
        </td>
        <td>@song.Fightsong.songname</td>
        <td>@song.Fightsong.duration</td>
        <td><a href="@Url.Content(@song.Fightsong.songurl)" class="playbtn"><i data-songid="@Url.Content(@song.Fightsong.FightSongId.ToString())" class="fa fa-play"></i></a></td>
        <td>@song.Fightsong.PlayCount</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Here is my script.  The code for the playbutton change stops before var clickedSongId.  That is to count the number of clicks so please disregard.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.playbtn').click(function () {
        var className = i.getAttribute("class");
        if (className == "fa-play") {
            i.className == "fa-pause"
        }
        var clickedSongId = $(this).find('i').data('songid');
        var fightsong = { Id: clickedSongId };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePlayCount", "Team")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //data: fightsong,
            data: JSON.stringify(fightsong),
            dataType: "json"

        });            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
if ($('.playbtn i[class*=fa-play]').length > 0) {
    $('.playbtn i[class*=fa-play]').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
} else if ($('.playbtn i[class*=fa-pause]').length > 0) {
    $('.playbtn i[class*=fa-pause]').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
}
```

Here is a more detailed version -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.playbtn').click(function() {
    if ($('.playbtn i[class*=fa-play]').length > 0) {
      $('.playbtn i[class*=fa-play]').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
    } else if ($('.playbtn i[class*=fa-pause]').length > 0) {
      $('.playbtn i[class*=fa-pause]').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
    }
    var clickedSongId = $(this).find('i').data('songid');
    var fightsong = {
      Id: clickedSongId
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePlayCount", "Team")',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      //data: fightsong,
      data: JSON.stringify(fightsong),
      dataType: "json"

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<tr>
  <td onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action(" Details ", "Team ", new {id = song.Teams.TeamId})'">
    <img src="#" height="35" width="35" />
  </td>
  <td>@song.Fightsong.songname</td>
  <td>@song.Fightsong.duration</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="playbtn"><i data-songid="#" class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
  </td>
  <td>@song.Fightsong.PlayCount</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is close.  It changes all of the pages icons.  I need it to just change the icon for that particular song.  Thanks

Comment: You just to provide an ID for that i tag

Comment: I can't assign that Id because this is a loop.  It will have 5 elements with that same ID.

Comment: I didnt see a difference in your code.  I assume I need to pass an Id from the song, which would be @song.Fightsong.FightSongId.  If I could set teh jquery to change the icon only when id = the id above, then that should work.  Right now it just changes all of them still.

Comment: If the class `playBtn` is used elsewhere and you have `i` tags / icons within that, the above code would change all of them. In which case, I'd say you'll have to re-consider that logic. If not, would you mind updating the question so I have a better idea of what's getting changed when you run the code?

Comment: I updated the code from using IDs to look at the `playBtn` class instead.. The idea is to use a selector that'll uniquely identify the icon you want changed

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that toggles between play and pause. I added [fixed width](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) to my solution since some icons are different width.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-play"></i>
  </h1>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $('.fa').click(function() {
    var wasPlay = $(this).hasClass('fa-play');
    $(this).removeClass('fa-play fa-pause');
    var klass = wasPlay ? 'fa-pause' : 'fa-play';
    $(this).addClass(klass)
  });
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/67j9i7DdM0XYHkybW6kg?p=preview)

Comment: This does not take into account that it is already in a $('.playbtn').click(function () {} event.  You solution does not work inside of this.  Thanks